# Unity Oculus Quest 2 Integration package stuck at Application.Reload on every second play

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I bought oculus quest 2 recently and using unity, i am trying to make games with it, but when i downloaded [Oculus Integration](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/oculus-integration-82022), and walked through [Getting started](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-gs-overview/),

- i downloaded the package
- downloaded oculus developer hub (and created developer account)
- paired the device and opened one of sample scenes

there was no problem, headset was working perfectly and i can interact with objects using controllers/hands,

until i try to test the game second time...

When i tried to play the game without changing anything second time, got this window

[image: EndlessWaitingWindow]

waited for few minutes then opened task manager just to see this

[image: RespondGoddemmit]

then i restarted the game, everything is fine... at the second play, all stuck at Application.Reload.

Made some testing with different setups :

- Opened completely new scene twice (**No problem**)
- Added the new scene an empty GameObject and added "OVR Camera Rig" and "OVR Manager" (**Problem Occurs**)
- Reloaded same scene at the run time (Scene reloads without problem, but **Problem Occurs**)
- Removed OVR Camera (**Problem Occurs**)
- Removed OVR Manager Added OVR Camera back (**No problem**)
- Played Scene with OVR Manager script First, then opened a completeley new scene (**Problem Occurs**)

I am using Unity 2020.3.12f1
Downloaded Oculus Integration 39.0

I'm out of ideas...

Edit : 
I found a workaround, for some reason OVR Manager Script causing this behaviour so i tried creating it on play mode and it worked!

So write a script that creates OVR Manager on start, but for some reason problem came back. Even though i created OVR Manager on play time (with addcomponent on start specifically) still editor stucks on starting the game.

**However my workaround is creating OVR Manager after 1 sec of game start...
I know its a petty solution but i can't lose more time...**

Feel free to Respond to this question maybe in future someone faces the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't solved this yet, updating to Unity 2020.3.35f solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing this problem as well after updating the Oculus Integration package to v39.

On your main scene, *deactivate* both **OVRCameraRig** and **InputOVR** prefab, then play the scene, you will notice you wont have this issue; Stop the scene; and now *activate* both the prefabs and play your scene like usual. (*you don't need to activate/deactivate the prefabs again*). It seem to be able to run without getting stuck at Application.Reload after I've done this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

@AdhamGhoname is right but if you have issues updating the Unity editor, update the Unity Hub as well then update the Unity Editor. You can access that by opening the Unity Hub and looking at the top bar.

My set up that removed the Application.Reload issue

- Oculus Integration v41
- Unity Editor 2021.3.5.f1
- Unity Hub 3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Same issue on Unity 2020.3.2f1 Windows 11

This seems to only happen if I'm on the Quest Link.

The first time I open the app and hit play it actually ignores the headset, then the second time it works, and the third time it gets stuck on Application.Reload

Comment: Adding the OVRManager on runtime worked for me.
Since this isn't an issue in the build I create the Manager on runtime and wait 1 second in the editor.

Just had to make sure to set my OVRRManager settings on the script, specifically trackingOriginType